# stl:map and mirrored data access

Tags: c++

I am getting data from a device that returns flow rate (double) and time (double). I want to store them and be able to access the data using both the flow rate to get the time and time to get the flow rate ...

I'm using two stl:map containers to do this ... is there a way to use only one container?

Here is the method to load the data: 
Flow data (sData) is a comma delimited string ("11.2, 22.3, 14.3, 12.4, 13.3")
Data is gathered each 0.25 seconds - so we just increment the time ...

```
void LiquidTest::Load(string sData)
{
  string sFlow;
  istringstream iss(sData);

  cout << "Inside LiquidTest::Load()." << endl;

  double dTime = 0.0;
  double dFlow = 0.0;

  while (getline(iss, sFlow, ','))
  {
    // add the flow/time to the map(s)
    cout << "Adding flow/time to map. sFlow=" << sFlow << ", dTime=" << dTime << "." << endl;

    // Convert my string to a double
    std::stringstream s(sFlow);
    s >> dFlow;

    // add the flow data and time data to the maps. We will then 
    // be able to access the flow by the time key and the time 
    // by the flow key.  Do I need two maps ??? 
    m_mapFlowDataKeyTime.insert(pair<double, double>(dFlow, dTime));
    m_mapTimeKeyFlowData.insert(pair<double, double>(dTime, dFlow));

    // Increment the time
    dTime += 0.25;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a map of doubles to search for elements is an issue because you cannot expect doubles to compare accurately, and there is a slight possibility it will allow duplicates in.

If you actually know there will be no duplicates in your data and no NaN values and you only want to sort values and make range-compares then you can go ahead and use map.

More likely what you want is a collection of structs or pairs, and some method of sorting them in two different ways. Boost has multi-index for that, or you can easily create your own by setting the sort criterion. You may want to have the data stored sorted in one criterion and then have an index on the other one.

If the data is static (i.e. loaded once then only searched) it is easy enough to maintain. If you are continually adding new items and removing items you need more careful maintenance.

A list is one way to store, as you can then index on iterators of the list, and these will not get invalidated as other elements are added later. It is also easy to remove these iterators if you want without invalidating other elements.

With your actual data, your time is just steps of 0.25 so you could actually just have a vector of double that represents flow and you know that the time in `flow[i]` is i/4. You could then have a second vector of int (or size_t) where initially `time[i]` is i but then you sort based on the other vector. Thus flow for `time[i]` is `flow[time[i]]` and you can sort based on that value (you will need a functor). You can then, using a similar functor, work out times where flow was a certain amount using binary search

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a bidirectional map and one common way to implement this is indeed to have two separate maps. Alternatively, you could also use some library implementation such as [Boost.Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html).